# Выравнивание блоков по странице django

Tags: django, bootstrap

У меня есть неизвестное количество блоков фиксированной ширины с некоторым текстом внутри, которые я хочу выровнять по странице по след. схеме: 2 блока в ширину, затем переход на след. строку и снова по два и т.д.

Я знаю, что можно сделать это с помощью сетки bootstrap, но не представляю как это сделать в цикле {{% for block in blocks %}}  (блоки создает пользователь, кол-во зависит от него).

К тому же блоки не имеют четко заданной высоты (она зависит от того, сколько текста внутрь введет пользователь).

Я новичок и буду рад любым идеям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
{% for block in blocks %}
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        {{ block }}
    </div>
    {% if forloop.counter1|divisibleby:"2" %} {# После каждого 2го блока вставляем выравниватель %}
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

---

Лучшее спасибо - принятие и голосование за ответ

Не за что